# Why did we use 2 region of integration?

Tags: integration

.[image]

In this case, why did we use two region of integration although x/2 is greater than y only in one case.
Note that initially, y is between 0 and 1 and that x is between square root of y and 2.

Comment: Have you drawn the region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this picture makes it clear. The region beneath $y=\frac14$ has a different left boundary from the region above that line. Algebraically, $\sqrt{y}>2y$ when $y<\frac14$, but not when $y>\frac14$

[image: Integration region]

This is the intersection of the two regions $\sqrt{y}<x<2$ (from the original setup) and $y<\frac{x}2$ (from the probability we're looking for now).